# jBox.js tooltip show on textbox focused and hide on unfucused

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, onfocus, jbox

When I clicked in text box `jbox.js` tooltip is showing, I want when text box **is focused** tooltip show and when **unfocused** tooltip hide.

**Script**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').jBox('Tooltip', {
        trigger: 'click',
        position: {
            x: 'right',
            y: 'center'
        },
        outside: 'x'
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML tag**:

```
<input type="text" class="tooltip" autofocus placeholder="First" id="fname" title="Your First Name in Latin" />
<input type="text" class="tooltip" placeholder="Last" id="lname" title="Your Last Name in Latin" />
<span class="lbl">Choose your username</span>
<input type="text" class="tooltip" id="uname" title="You Can Use letters, numbers, dots" />
<span class="lbl lbl_no">Username can't leave this empty.</span>
```

Comment: I Use jBox.js jquery based library for my tooltips

Comment: Proper code indentation.

Comment: you will be use of Close and Open function in jBox.js script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be use of focus and blur function in JQuery.
Your need code is :

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x = $('.tooltip').jBox('Tooltip', {
            trigger: 'focus',
            animation:{open: 'tada', close: 'flip'},
            position:{
             x:'right',
             y:'center'   
            }, outside:'x'
        });
        $('.tooltip').blur(function() {
            x.close();
        });
    });
</script>
```